# how to do an insert when the month is january in oracle using stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE spInsertSale2(SALES_ID in number,PRODUCT in varchar2,UNITCOST in decimal,QUANTITY in number)
AS
BEGIN
    if to_char(sysdate,'mm') from dual = '01' then
    {
        INSERT INTO Studenta_1004195.SALES VALUES(SALES_ID,PRODUCT,UNITCOST,QUANTITY);
    }endif
END spInsertSale2;
/
```

Comment: Hi, your question shouldn't be only code. Please describe what you're trying to do, and what problems what you have so far has.

Comment: curly braces are invalid in PL/SQL. Please read the PL/SQL reference manual.

Answer (score 2):

your syntax is off:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE spInsertSale2(
  SALES_ID in number,PRODUCT in varchar2,UNITCOST in decimal,QUANTITY in number)
AS
BEGIN
    if to_char(sysdate,'mm') = '01' then
        INSERT INTO Studenta_1004195.SALES 
        VALUES(SALES_ID,PRODUCT,UNITCOST,QUANTITY);
    end if;
END spInsertSale2;
/
```

Comment: @russian no problem. i'd recommend you specify the column names on that insert (eg `insert into Studenta_1004195.SALES (a,b,c,d) values (sales_id...)` and also use `%type` on the parameter declarations instead of putting `number` etc. putting the columns on means that if someone adds a nullable column (or not null with default), your code will still work.

Answer (score 1):

at first glance, it appears you are missing the word "select"

```
AS BEGIN
if
this is where you are missing the word select
to_char(sysdate, 'mm') = '01'
etc
```

Comment: when i add the select i still get the warning that the procedure was created with compilation errors